# Notetoself Icon Add donn't appear

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm new to Android Programming. I'm following the guide on Android Developers to get started with Android. When trying to run simple Note on the Emulator,the emulator Shows me  an Errors... according the book musst appear a Icon and add a note ,,note that if you add a second note ,it will overwrite the first because i only have one Note object   the Problem is that Icon Add donn't appear

*dialog_new_note*

```
   <RelativeLayout      
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:hint="@string/title_hint" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editDescription"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:hint="@string/description_hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/idea_checkbox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxIdea"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editDescription"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:checked="false" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/todo_checkbox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxTodo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxIdea"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:checked="false" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/important_checkbox"
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxImportant"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxTodo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:checked="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cancel_button"
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBoxImportant"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editTitle"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTitle" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ok_button"
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="53dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>



 Dialog_show_note
```

> 

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewTodo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewImportant"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewImportant"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_box_black_24dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewIdea"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewTodo"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewTodo"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_wb_incandescent_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewIdea"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/btnOK"
    android:layout_marginBottom="101dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTitle" />
   </RelativeLayout>

     **menu_main.xml**
```

> **Content_main.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Note"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**string_xml**
     
    Note To Self
    Settings

```
<string name="action_add">add</string>
<string name="title_hint">Title</string>
<string name="description_hint">Description</string>
<string name="idea_checkbox">Idea</string>
<string name="important_checkbox">Important</string>
<string name="todo_checkbox">To do</string>
<string name="cancel_button">Cancel</string>
<string name="ok_button">OK</string>


<string name="sound_checkbox">On or Of</string>
<string name="settings_title">Settings</string>
<string name="sound_title">Sound</string>
<string name="amims_title">Animation Speed</string>
<string name="rb_fast">Fast</string>
<string name="rb_slow">Slow</string>
<string name="rb_none">None</string>


  </resources>
**DialogNewNote**

       > 



   public class DialogNewNote extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_note, null);

      final EditText editTitle = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
       final EditText editDescription = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editDescription);
       final CheckBox checkBoxIdea = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxIdea);
      final CheckBox checkBoxTodo = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTodo);
       final CheckBox checkBoxImportant = (CheckBox) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxImportant);
      Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
      Button btnOK = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

    builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Add a new mNote");

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Handle the OK button
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create a new note
            Note newNote = new Note();

            // Set its variables to match the users entries on the form
            newNote.setTitle(editTitle.getText().toString());
            newNote.setDescription(editDescription.getText().toString());
            newNote.setIdea(checkBoxIdea.isChecked());
            newNote.setTodo(checkBoxTodo.isChecked());
            newNote.setImportant(checkBoxImportant.isChecked());

            // Get a reference to MainActivity
            MainActivity callingActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

            // Pass newNote back to MainActivity
            callingActivity.createNewNote(newNote);

            // Quit the dialog
            dismiss();
        }
    });





    return builder.create();

}
```

}

```
   > 


    public class DialogShowNote  extends DialogFragment {

private Note mNote;

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Receive a note from the MainActivity


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_show_note, null);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView txtDescription = (TextView)    dialogView.findViewByI                  (R.id.tx         tDescription);           
    txtTitle.setText(mNote.getTitle());
    txtDescription.setText(mNote.getDescription());
    ImageView ivImportant = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImportant);
    ImageView ivTodo = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTodo);
    ImageView ivIdea = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIdea);


    if (!mNote.isImportant()) {
        ivImportant.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (!mNote.isTodo()) {
        ivTodo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (!mNote.isIdea()) {
        ivIdea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    Button btnOK = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    builder.setView(dialogView).setMessage("Your Note");
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();


}

public void sendNoteSelected(Note noteSelected) {
    mNote = noteSelected;


}
 }
```

> 

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Temporary code
Note mTempNote = new Note();

@Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Temporary code
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Create a new DialogShowNote called dialog
            DialogShowNote dialog = new DialogShowNote();

            // Send the note via the sendNoteSelected method
            dialog.sendNoteSelected(mTempNote);

            // Create the dialog
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "123");
        }
    });

    }

public void createNewNote(Note n){
    // Create a mNote
    mTempNote = n;
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
     }

    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_add) {
        DialogNewNote dialog = new DialogNewNote();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }
```

**5-16 15:32:20.654 2673-2673/com.example.melisa.notetoself W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.melisa.notetoself-2/lib/x86
05-16 15:32:20.934 2673-2673/com.example.melisa.notetoself W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-16 15:32:20.975 2673-2741/com.example.melisa.notetoself D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-16 15:32:21.042 2673-2741/com.example.melisa.notetoself I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-16 15:32:23.438 2673-2741/com.example.melisa.notetoself E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae3f2e30**